# Angular calculations ngfor cumulative value and total via parent

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get the cumulative total of a list of values in an *ngFor loop, but the value must be returned to the parent and then passed to the next item in the for loop and thus the parent would know the total also. Code sandbox can be found at: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-test-01-n0hme?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The values are not calculated on an event but during the ngFor, no user interaction.

1. A count from the ngFor (not using index) for title "list no {{ count }}"
2. Cumulative total of the ngFor but also next item in for loop has access to this value.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

D

File: app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test-app';

  listNo = 0;
  totalPriceOfAllLists: number = 0;

  lists = [
    {
      name: "item list 1",
      items: [{ name: "item 1", value: 10 }, { name: "item 2", value: 10 }]
    },
    {
      name: "item list 2",
      items: [
        { name: "item 1", value: 10 },
        { name: "item 2", value: 10 },
        { name: "item 3", value: 10 }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "item list 3",
      items: [
        { name: "item 1", value: 10 },
        { name: "item 2", value: 10 },
        { name: "item 3", value: 10 },
        { name: "item 4", value: 10 }
      ]
    }
  ];

}
```

File: app.component.html

```
<h2>Test App</h2>

<app-item
  *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index;"
  [listIndex]="i"
  [list]="list"
></app-item>

<b>Total £ {{totalPriceOfAllLists}}</b>

<hr />
<div class="">
  list no 1 cumulativeTotal should be £20<br />
  list no 1 cumulativeTotal should be £50<br />
  list no 1 cumulativeTotal should be £90<br />
  Total should be £160
</div>
```

File: item.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterViewChecked } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-item",
  templateUrl: "./item.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./item.component.css"]
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() listIndex: number; // shouldn't use index as it should be a counter increment from parent
  @Input() list: { name: string; value: number }[];

  listNo = 0;
  cumaliativeTotal = 0;

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.list);
    this.getListTotal();
  }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {}

  getListTotal() {
    let total: number = 0;
    this.list.items.forEach(item => {
      total += item.value;
    });
    this.listTotal = total;
  }
}
```

File: item.component.html

```
<div class="item">
  <!-- do not use index which is available as i -->
  <h4>List no {{ listNo }}</h4>

  <div *ngFor="let item of list.items;">
    {{ item.name }} - £{{ item.value }}
  </div>

  <p><b>List total £{{ listTotal }}</b></p>
  <p><b>Cumulative total £{{ cumulativeTotal }}</b></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The link is not working.

Comment: I've tested link on a browser I'm not singed in with and also vpn enabled and it works fine, try this link: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-test-01-n0hme?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass values from child to parent component in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228423/how-to-pass-values-from-child-to-parent-component-in-angular-4)

Comment: That is using EventEmitter on user interaction, what I'm trying to do is inthe for loop itself, no user interaction. Unless I have to push custom event manually for each time the child is run, but shouldn't there be a nicer / better way of doing that without using eventemitter? Output? maybe?

Answer (score 1):

seems to be easier to me to just calculate this all in code one time:

in app component:

```
setListTotals(list) {

  const listWithTotals = list.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const listTotal = val.items.reduce((a, v) => a += v.value, 0)
    const cumulativeTotal = listTotal + acc.reduce((a, v) => a += v.cumulativeTotal, 0)
    return acc.concat([{...val, listTotal, cumulativeTotal}])
  }, [])

  return {listWithTotals, totalPrice: listWithTotals.reduce((a,v) => a += v.listTotal, 0)}
}

vm;
ngOnInit() {
  this.vm = this.setListTotals(this.lists);
}
```

and in template:

```
<h2>Test App</h2>

<app-item
  *ngFor="let list of vm.listWithTotals; let i = index;"
  [listIndex]="i"
  [list]="list"
></app-item>

<b>Total £ {{vm.totalPrice}}</b>
```

and child:

```
<div class="item">
  <!-- do not use index which is available as i -->
  <h4>List no {{ listNo }}</h4>

  <div *ngFor="let item of list.items;">
    {{ item.name }} - £{{ item.value }}
  </div>

  <p><b>List total £{{ list.listTotal }}</b></p>
  <p><b>Cumulative total £{{ list.cumulativeTotal }}</b></p>
</div>
```

rerun the set list totals function whenever the list changes and you're done.

forked sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-test-01-70lw3

Comment: Not sure how that helps, please fork the sandbox, but if it does what I think it does this is just a total of the list that is passed to the child and the parent has no idea about the cumulative total.

The child need to calculate the total (which it already does), then once this total has been calculated it needs to pass it to the parent. The next iteration of the for loop uses the parents cumulativeTotal variable to add to the listTotal it calculates. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: I expanded on exactly how it would work.  This whole child back to parent nonsense is a waste of time and overly complex.  Just let the parent run the calculations to build the vm and pass the full vm to the children

Comment: Ah, your mutating the data and feeding that into ngfor instead of doing all the passing of data etc. Is there a way however so that it can be calculated in the child and that value passed to the parent and having the parent's ngfor [cumulative]=cumulative passed to the child on each iteration? For me this is more of an excercise on child handling things and data synchronisation between parent and child over the iterations rather than the mutation of data to a new formatted object/vo so a child has nothing to do but dump out values.

Comment: it's poor architecture.  data in angular should be flowing up or down the tree, not both ways at once.  Generally you should have smart containers (or preferably services) that know how to do things like calculate or build a vm and dumb children that just display data.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do it child to parent communications for some scenarios eg. Say you query a db and get a return of 50,000 list items each list item has between 50 and 500 items within it. Would you still mutate the 50,000 items object or would you use the child to just do the calculation on the 1 iteartion saving having create a new object/vo of 50,000 item just with some extra data objects/values in it?

Comment: the number of calculations I'm running and new objects I'm creating and the amount of code I'm writing is the same. I'd do it up front for sure to preserve good angular architecture.  Inputs give children data to display, Outputs transmit user events back to the parent so they can do something with the event. In the real world, I can't display 50,000 items with 50-500 sub items at once anyway.  So hopefully I'd be paging there or finding some way of ensuring I'm only calculating these things when I need to

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this is what you want. If not let me know.I'll update the answer accordingly.
>   https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-test-01-gxif7

Since you have whole list in your parent component, why don't you calculate Cumulative total in side the parent component and pass it to child component. Add new property called **cumulativeTotal** to your list objects.

So then your list should be like below.

```
lists = [
    {
      name: "item list 1",
      items: [{ name: "item 1", value: 10 }, { name: "item 2", value: 10 }],
      cumulativeTotal:0 
    },
    {
      name: "item list 2",
      items: [
        { name: "item 1", value: 10 },
        { name: "item 2", value: 10 },
        { name: "item 3", value: 10 }
      ],
     cumulativeTotal:0
    },
    {
      name: "item list 3",
      items: [
        { name: "item 1", value: 10 },
        { name: "item 2", value: 10 },
        { name: "item 3", value: 10 },
        { name: "item 4", value: 10 }
      ],
     cumulativeTotal:0
    }
  ];
```

And you should have a new method to calculate cumulative total for each list and the total price of all lists .

```
 calculateCumulativeTotal(list) {
    list.forEach(item => {
      item.cumulativeTotal = item.items.reduce(
        (cumulativeTotal, k) => cumulativeTotal + k.value,
        0
      );
    });

    this.totalPriceOfAllLists = list.reduce(
      (cumulativeTotal, k) => cumulativeTotal + k.cumulativeTotal,
      0
    );
  }
```

This is your **app.component.html**

```
<h2>Test App</h2>

<app-item
  *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index;"
  [listIndex]="i"
  [list]="list"
></app-item>

<b>Total £ {{totalPriceOfAllLists}}</b>

<hr />
<div class="">
  <span *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index;">
    list no {{i}} cumulativeTotal should be £{{list.cumulativeTotal}}<br />
  </span>
  Total should be £{{totalPriceOfAllLists}}
</div>
```

This is your **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Oninit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements Oninit {
  title = "test-app";
  lists: any = [];
  listNo = 0;
  totalPriceOfAllLists: number = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lists = [
      {
        name: "item list 1",
        items: [{ name: "item 1", value: 10 }, { name: "item 2", value: 10 }],
        cumulativeTotal: 0
      },
      {
        name: "item list 2",
        items: [
          { name: "item 1", value: 10 },
          { name: "item 2", value: 10 },
          { name: "item 3", value: 10 }
        ],
        cumulativeTotal: 0
      },
      {
        name: "item list 3",
        items: [
          { name: "item 1", value: 10 },
          { name: "item 2", value: 10 },
          { name: "item 3", value: 10 },
          { name: "item 4", value: 10 }
        ],
        cumulativeTotal: 0
      }
    ];

    this.calculateCumulativeTotal(this.lists);
  }

  calculateCumulativeTotal(list) {
    list.forEach(item => {
      item.cumulativeTotal = item.items.reduce(
        (cumulativeTotal, k) => cumulativeTotal + k.value,
        0
      );
    });

    this.totalPriceOfAllLists = list.reduce(
      (cumulativeTotal, k) => cumulativeTotal + k.cumulativeTotal,
      0
    );
  }
}
```

This is your **item.component.html**

```
<div class="item">
  <!-- do not use index which is available as i -->
  <h4>List no {{ listIndex }}</h4>

  <div *ngFor="let item of list.items;">
    {{ item.name }} - £{{ item.value }}
  </div>

  <p><b>List total £{{ listTotal }}</b></p>
  <p><b>Cumulative total £{{ list.cumulativeTotal }}</b></p>
</div>
```

This is your **item.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-item",
  templateUrl: "./item.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./item.component.css"]
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() listIndex: number; // shouldn't use index as it should be a counter increment from parent
  @Input() list: { name: string; value: number }[];

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.list);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Drenai we don't need those. I have removed that. Thanks for pointing out.